# symfony 2.5 many to one relation foreign key null

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys, many-to-one, symfony-2.5

i have two entities produit entity and avis with a many to one relation one product can have many avis but when i try to save a comment the field produit_id stay null. i have well configured the relation i think that i have a problem in the controller.

this is my controller add avis action:

```
public function addAction(Request $request){
    $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $produit=$em->getRepository('redeBundle:produit')->findAll();
    $avis = new avis();
    $avis->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    $form = $this->createForm(new avisType(), $avis);
    $form -> handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
       $avis->setProduit($produit);
        $em->persist($avis);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('produit_page'));
    }

    $formView=$form->createView();

    return $this->render('myBundle:avisAdd.html.twig',
     array('form'=>$formView));

}
```

this is my entity avis

```
class avis {

/**
 * @var produit
 *
 * @Assert\valid()
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="redemaroc\redeBundle\Entity\produit", 
cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 *
 *
 */
private $produit;

 ...
 }
```

can someone help me resolve that ?!

Answer (score 0):

It is solvable by using on of those solutions

1. in the setProduit method of your Avis class, you add the following instruction: **produit->addAvis($this);**.
2. Make sure that anytime you call **$avis->setProduit($produit);**, you must add **$produit->addAvis($avis);** before flush your data.

I am supposing that *addAvis* is the method used to add a given avis to your produit.